# ADC giving strange output for PIC16F15325

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, adc

I was trying to read analog voltage on pin RC3 on PIC16F15325. I have 3.23V across potentiometer and its output is nearly 1.65V which goes to pin RC3 of PIC microcontroller. For configuration and libraries I used MPLAB Code Cofigurator. Code is as follows:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"


void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    EUSART1_Initialize();
    ADC_Initialize();
    
    adc_result_t val1 = 0;
    

    // When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
    // Use the following macros to:

    // Enable the Global Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

    // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

    // Disable the Global Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();

    // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
    //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();

    while (1)
    {
        // Add your application code
        val1 = ADC_GetConversion(19); // selected channel RC3
        printf("Value - %hu \n",val1);
        DELAY_milliseconds(1000);
    }
}
```

For voltage I mentioned above, I expected value near "511". Anything beyond 1023 [i.e. (2^10) - 1] is strange as PIC has 10-bit ADC.However uotput I get is:

[image: Output from PIC16F15325 on TeraTerm terminal.]

Kindly, help me solving this issue.

Comment: If you want help you must show your complete program, not just the mainloop. Do you really think RC3 is channel 19?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, insert it as text. And yes, you can copy-n-paste from TeraTerm.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, output was correct but was looking strange only because of format. Just now I looked into datasheet which said about 2 ways of ADC result formatting.

[PIC16(L)F15325/45 Datasheet page-228](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jczK0.png)

and inside `ADC_Initialize();` ADCON1 = 0x10 which means ADFM is left shift. I just did `val1 = val1 >> 6;` after `ADC_GetConversion(19);` and it worked as expected.